# How to interact a front End with smart contracts and blockchain in mobile Dapps?

Tags: mobile, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

i want to build a mobile DeFi wallet but i'm wondering how to interact my front End with smart contracts and the ethereum blockchain. Please help me. Will i use truffle in it like other web Dapps ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your frontend needs to be connected the same way as if it was for desktop. There's no difference at all in how the connections are done. In the end, you have your contracts, and you can interact with them with libraries such as web3.js, ethers.js and any others. What do you to then create a mobile version, is up to you.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Did you have a work or guide to do that.

Comment: You can google for web3.js, ethers.js, those are JavaScript libraries to interact with contracts.

Comment: I did that but it doesn't work.